# How to download the whole transfer records of a token

Tags: ether, tokens

I want download the whole transfer records of a token. https://etherscan.io/token/0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52?a=0xd551234ae421e3bcba99a0da6d736074f22192ff.
But the default setting is 2000. It means you can only export the earliest 2000 records starting from some date time. What can I do if the records more then 2000?
https://etherscan.io/exportData?type=tokentxns&contract=0xB8c77482e45F1F44dE1745F52C74426C631bDD52&a=0xd551234ae421e3bcba99a0da6d736074f22192ff&decimal=18

Comment: I usually copy it from wallet or the block chain, then save it in another dedicated file

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, you can do it if the number is not too large. But I have total about 10k transactions, I think it cannot work in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze all transactions since the deploy of the token contract. Then filter for transactions that call `transfer()` and `transferFrom()` on the token contract

Comment: sorry, I am not familiar with the api or code. I just want to download from the page..:(

Comment: You'll never be sure if the data on the website is completely accurate and complete.